# Optimization in WHERE clause seems to be not working with UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have tried an SQL script in the following format. (There are multiple joins to produce set1, set2, and set3 but removed them for simplicity).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Set1
    WHERE someConditions
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Set2
    WHERE someConditions
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM Set3
    WHERE @include = 1 AND otherConditions..
) as t
ORDER BY ...
```

One would expect that when `@include = 0`, the entirety of the last `UNION` will be ignored. This is also what I have seen when looked up for conditionally doing `UNION`.

But this is not the case for me; the query takes a long time to execute even when `@include = 0`. If I comment-out the last section the query will execute much faster.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Set1
    WHERE someConditions
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Set2
    WHERE someConditions
    --UNION 
    --SELECT * FROM Set3
    --WHERE @include = 1 AND otherConditions..
) as t
ORDER BY ...
```

Why the compiler is not able to pick this up? Is there any way to optimize queries in such scenarios?

Comment: *Maybe* try with [`option (recompile)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Or use dynamic SQL and create a query that only includes the parts you need. Also, do you really need `UNION`, or would `UNION ALL` still produce the correct results? `UNION` is a far more costly operator and should only be used if you really need it.

Comment: Just a hunch, but can you try replacing all 'Union' occurrences with 'Union All' and then convert your outer 'select' to 'select distinct'.  The query engine might be more likely to treat the three query components separately in this way.

Comment: `option (recompile)` and `UNION ALL` did not make a difference for me. Might have to go with dynamic SQL as a last resort.

Comment: @eshirvana No; Added for the entire query, at the end. We can't add `recompile` for inner queries, can we? It is resulting in a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, OPTION(RECOMPILE) worked well on a simiilar test set-up - reusing the poor plan without the hint (assuming previously run with @include = 1) but creating a new, better plan when using RECOMPILE.

If that doesn't work for you, you could try splitting into two distinct statements using IF, eg:

```
BEGIN
IF @include = 1 
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM Set1
    WHERE someConditions
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Set2
    WHERE someConditions
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM Set3
    WHERE otherConditions..

END

ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Set1
    WHERE someConditions
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Set2
    WHERE someConditions
END
END
```

Comment: For some reason, recompile is not helping me. But I like this idea of splitting up even though it might not do good for maintenance.